# How to replace template with my own content, xml Odoo 14

Tags: python, xml, odoo, qweb

I need to replace the template `variants` of the `sale` module using my own content.

My code-xml:

```
<template id="my_variants" inherit_id="sale.variants">
  <xpath expr="." position="replace">
     <!--        <p>My codee, this is not shown</p>-->
  </xpath>
</template>
```

using the previous code my new template does not work, what am I doing wrong? how do I solve it?

Note: use `<t t-call = "web.layout">` with all content after the xpath; my template works but shows a JS error

Code with error JS:

```
   <template id="my_variants" inherit_id="sale.variants">
      <xpath expr="." position="replace"><!-- template works but with error JS-->
        <t t-call="web.layout" >
         <!--        <p>My codee, my code, this is displayed and</p>-->
        </t>
      </xpath>
    </template>
```

JS error:

> web.assets_common_lazy.js:4497 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot
> read property 'user_context' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code:

```
<template id="my_variants" inherit_id="sale.variants">
    <xpath expr="." position="replace">
        <p>My codee, this is not shown</p>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

The paragraph will be shown to the left of the item price in the `Available Options`

Do not use `<t t-call="web.layout" >` inside `variants` template, the `product` template already did that.

`web.layout` is usually used when we add a new layout.